# Changing fragment in activity vs new activity

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, android-activity, responsive-design

I am trying to follow all best practices and designs of mobile app (in this in Android).

There are a lot different ways to show new representation to user.
Creating new activity, changing part of activity(fragment) or chang fragment in signle fragment activity.

So what is the best and most acceptable way to do this.

For example in such case. I have list of categories and I need to open description of some product, what should I do in this way create new activity with its content or just change fragment in current activity.

If use second approach that means that I will have one activity in app, and will just change fragments inside it, so one activity responsible for all.

Please suggest what is the most correct way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear... what do you want actually..you can use navigation drawer from the right to give/display product info...orelse have viewpagers vertically and for individual vertical viewpager have 1/2 pager horizontally

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the requirements of the application. Check official design guide : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Design pattern can be different depending on whether your app will support both handsets and tablets. Multi-pane layouts will come handy in such a case, as listed in above design guide. 
Hope this helps.